# Tensorflow regression data normalization before inputting into neural network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I have to perform a regression which maps 100 dimensional vector inputs to 100 dimensional vector outputs. Both, the inputs and outputs lie in the range of 0 to 1200.
I am using 4 layer MLP (multi layer perceptron) built using tensorflow fully connected layers. As is commonly suggested, I normalized the inputs, so that they lie in the range 0-1. Thus, I divided the input data by the maximum value it attains. 
However, such an approach failed to produce any useful result (I did not normalize the outputs though).
Thereafter, I did not normalize the inputs, and repeated the MLP experiment. This time, the neural network performed quite well.
I think that due to normalization, all the activations were close to 0, and failed to "catch-up to the outputs". What am I missing here? Should we always normalize the inputs/ or not?

Comment: Normalization is a "hyperparameter" choice, as any data preprocessing is. It might make better or worse. It depends on many factors, for example the type(s) of activation function(s), loss function, optimizer algorithms, the kind of initialization and regularization you use. Also, failed approach might not actually be a failure, you just might have not find a good set of hyperparams. You might also try to de-normalize the outputs back. Make sure you calculate metrics correctly in all cases. It is a research topic, so there is very little StackOverflow can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific application, the normalization you used made you lose valuable information. consider the following two inputs before normalization:

```
x1 = [2, ..., 10, ...] # 2 is min, 10 is max
x2 = 5*x1
```

you can see that `max(x2) = 5*max(x1)`, thus, after normalization both samples are equal.

So, in your case, it seems like the scale information is important. losing it resulted in poor results. In different applications (image processing for example) this may not be the case and such normalization will help to make the learning process more smooth.

Why is the scale important in your application? I'm not sure. But I can give you an example from the medical imaging domain. In CT scans, every pixel value corresponds to a HU value, which is essentially a metric of density in that specific location. Assuming we have two images with a similar pattern like the samples on top, `x1` can correspond to a an image mainly containing soft tissue and `x2` bone. Do we want normalize both to the same sample? probably not.

I think the link below is a good resource to further read about normalization/standardization:

http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#about-standardization

Comment: thanks for the link, I will go through it....Though, I didnt get the max(x2)=5*max(x1) part...I meant that of course, multiplying the vector does increase its magnitude, but in theory, the neural network is allowed to multiply the inputs, so it can recover the original scale by itself....

Comment: if you normalize, you get that `x1 = x1/10` and `x2=5*x1/5*10=x1/10`. then both samples are equal after normalization. This is in contrast to what you said, that the network will be able to recover the original scale.

Comment: Hi Amir, I think there is some problem in communication of ideas. In the following, I will be using latex style for mathematical content (I could not figure out how to use latex on this website).

 In neural networks, if x is inputs, then the first layer's j-th neuron receives the following inputs  \sum x_i w_{i,j} + b_j , where b_j is the bias and w_{i,j} are multiplicative constants. Thus, theoretically, letting x_i \to x_i/10 should not be an issue, since we can always let w_{i,j} \to 10w_{i,j}, thereby cancelling the effect of scaling the inputs

Comment: when you normalized your input, did you normalize by per sample, per feature or just divided by the highest value in the entire train set?

Comment: divided by the highest value in the entire data set (highest value in the combined train and test)

Comment: In my answer I assumed that you divided by the maximum number per sample. If you divided by the maximum value in train/test there shouldn't be any difference in performance. Can you share code?